# Json querying (count and grouping) in javascript or groovy

Tags: javascript, json, groovy

I need to make queries (like counting some nodes or grouping nodes) from a 
large json.
I need this to show some graphs and reports in html.

This could be in groovy or json.

Do you know any lib to do this?

Thanks a lot 
Federico

Comment: I need focus on grouping and counting instead just finding.

Comment: something like that: http://jsonpath.com/